# Not able to load child module by navigate()

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

there is a "layout" path defined in app-routing.module.ts file and i am tring to load this child module through below method(defined in auth.component.ts)----- this.router.navigate(['/layout']);

why i am not able to load child module?

Code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {AuthComponent} from './auth/auth.component';
import {LayoutModule} from './layout/layout.module';
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'auth', children: [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'login', component: AuthComponent}
 ]},
{ path: 'layout', loadChildren:() => LayoutModule},
];
  @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: did you put <router-outlet></router-outlet> in app.component

Comment: yes. i have added.

Comment: which angular version your using?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildrenCallback#description _This function must match the form above: an arrow function of the form () => import('...').then(mod => mod.MODULE)._

Comment: Note that the above wont fully work with angular versions lower than 8

Comment: I am using Angular 7. @SoumyaGangamwar

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic import should return a function with the path and will return a promise with the module, it should look like this:

```
{ path: 'layout', loadChildren:() => import{'./layout/layout.module')
.then(m => m.LayoutModule)},
```

Answer (score 0):

When routes at app level,

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: 'customers',
loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(mod => mod.CustomersModule)
},
{
path: 'orders',
 loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(mod => mod.OrdersModule)
},
{
path: '',
redirectTo: '',
pathMatch: 'full'
 }
];
```

[reference](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#routes-at-the-app-level)

> The first two paths are the routes to the CustomersModule and the OrdersModule respectively. Notice that the lazy loading syntax uses loadChildren followed by a function that uses the browser's built-in import('...') syntax for dynamic imports. The import path is the relative path to the module.

Or

```
{ path: 'lazymodule', loadChildren: './lazymodule/lazymodule.module#LazyModuleModule' }
```

refer this [link](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-routing-lazy-loading-loadchildren/)